# Как определить, что установлен русский офис?

Tags: excel, office

Как определить, что на заданном компьютере установлен русский офис или, конкретно, Excel?

UPD. Т.е. требуется узнать о наличии локализации офиза. Проверку требуется сделать из сторонней программы. Нужны какие-либо данные из реестра или файла.

Comment: А как определять? кодом (тогда на каком языке программирования) или визуально?

Comment: Как из макроса проверить, русский он или нет? Или как из сторонней программы проверить, что он установлен и определить язык?

Comment: Вопрос обновил.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Для последних версий офиса, локализируемых через MUI, можно проверить на наличие ключей в ветках

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\LanguageResources
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\LanguageResources\InstalledUIs
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\LanguageResources
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\LanguageResources\InstalledUIs
```

1049 - это [LCID](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179219.aspx) для Russian.

Список ключей:

- InstallLanguage - основной язык для редактирования.
- EnabledLanguages - список установленных языков редактирования.
- UILanguage - текущий язык интерфейса.
- InstalledUIs - список установленных языков интерфейса.

[источник - Technet Office Resource Kit blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2010/04/02/how-to-determine-which-2007office-system-languages-are-installed.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала следует определить установлен ли Excell вообще. Посылаем запрос на наличие файла C:\program files\microsoft office\office14\excell.exe - это для офиса 2010 в 32-битной системе.
потом проверяем его локализацию по наличию файла c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\1049\XLINTL32.DLL
как-то так

Comment: Чтобы проверить наличие Excel-я нужно из реестра  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\<версия>\Excel\InstallRoot::Path получить путь папки инсталляции, и в ней проверить наличие файла EXCEL.EXE.

Comment: _"потом проверяем его локализацию по наличию файла c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\1049\XLINTL32.DLL"_ это верно для всех офисов с 2007? А ссылку на описание XLINTL32.DLL можете подкинуть?

Comment: [вот ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/post/248597/) - тут правда, немного о другом, но частично затрагивается и Ваша тема. Ваш пример для InstallRoot естественно, наиболее приемлем, ибо неизвестно в какой версии будет работать разрабатываемое ПО